# Downsampling a 2d numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm self learning python and have found a problem which requires down sampling a feature vector.  I need some help understanding how down-sampling a array. in the array each row represents an image by being number from `0` to `255`. I was wonder how you apply down-sampling to the array? I don't want to `scikit-learn` because I want to understand how to apply down-sampling.
If you could explain down-sampling too that would be amazing thanks.

the feature vector is 400x250

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If with downsampling you mean something [like this](http://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/downsample.html), you can simply slice the array. For a 1D example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1,11,1)
print(a)
print(a[::3])
```

The last line is equivalent to:

```
print(a[0:a.size:3])
```

with the slicing notation as `start:stop:step`

Result:

> [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
>
> [ 1  4  7 10]

For a 2D array the idea is the same:

```
b = np.arange(0,100)
c = b.reshape([10,10])
print(c[::3,::3])
```

This gives you, in both dimensions, every third item from the original array.

Or, if you only want to down sample a single dimension:

```
d = np.zeros((400,250))
print(d.shape)
e = d[::10,:]
print(e.shape)
```

> (400, 250)
>
> (40, 250)

The are lots of other examples in [the Numpy manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: but how do you do this for a 2d array

Comment: I updated the answer. But I'm not sure to what size you want to downsample your original 400x250 array?

Comment: Saying _"this doesn't work"_ isn't very helpful. What doesn't work? Or even better: could you provide a simple example of exactly how the down sampling should work (e.g., from a 2D array `[[0,1,..,9],[10,11,..,19]`, the down sampled array should contain elements `[[1,3,..],[11,13,..]]`)? Which items should be kept? Or you mention that you don't want to use `scikit-learn`, but which routine should it reproduce?

Comment: I don't think this can answer what OP was trying to ask. What he meant is [down-sampling in Machine Learning](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/data-prep/construct/sampling-splitting/imbalanced-data).

Comment: @Phan Nhat Huy, yes, now (5-6 years later) I would also interpret OP's question different. Feel free to write an answer more suitable for ML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to downsample along certain dimensions, you can use `mean`, which not only decimates, but also downsamples. Below example: Downsamples an ndarray of size `(h,w,3)` along axes 0,1, but not along dim 3:

```py
def downsample_2x(arrayn3d):
    """
        Downsamples an ndarray of size `(h,w,3)` along axes 0,1 (along w,h)
        Input can be non-float, e.g. uint8
    """
    dtype1 = array3d.dtype
    a = array3d.astype(float)
    (h,w,_) = a.shape
    assert w % 2 == 0
    assert h % 2 == 0
    w2 = int(w/2)
    h2 = int(h/2)
    a = a.reshape((h,w2,2,3))
    a = np.mean(a, axis=2)
    assert a.shape == (h,w2,3)
    a = a.reshape((h2,2,w2,3))
    a = np.mean(a, axis=1)
    assert a.shape == (h2,w2,3)
    a = np.floor(a).astype(dtype1)
    return a
```

Which gives a matrix of size `(w/2,h/2,3)`. If w and h are not even numbers, it will be slightly more complicated.
This is not the most efficient way to do it, but the steps and ideas should be clear.

Answer (score -1):

from skimage.measure import block_reduce 
new_matrix=block_reduce(Matrix_for_downsample,block_size=(m,n),func=np.mean/np.max/..)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question explicitly mentions that OP does not want to use `scikit-learn`.